# Encoding of latin characters like £ (pound) is throwing junk value after encoding using perl script

Tags: mysql, perl

I am trying to encode the '£' and inserted into DB it is storing as 'Â£',while fetching it is displaying as  Â£, I am decoded this data , but eventhough it is displaying as Â£.Using perl script , Here is my code.

```
#!/usr/local/perl-5.20.1/bin/perl
use HTML::Entities;
$str="£";
$str=HTML::Entities::encode($str);
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO notes VALUES (null,'FD',?,?)");
$sth->execute('1','2',time(),$str);
$sth = $dbh->execute("SELECT content FROM notes WHERE requestID = 1);
while (my @temp = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
 $note = HTML::Entities::decode($temp[0]);
}
```

In terminal it is displaying as Â£ after decoding of fetched DB data  (Â£)

Comment: Can you please add the exact outut from your terminal and check the encoding of you file?

Comment: I am trying to encode the '£' and inserted into DB it is storing as '&Acirc;&pound;',while fetching it is displaying as  Â£, I am decoded this data , but eventhough it is displaying as Â£.Using perl script ,

Comment: You've already said that in the question. But without additional information it's impossible to understand what is going on. **Please [edit] your question** and add your complete terminal output, including how you run the script and what it prints.

Comment: I have changed the question along with brief explaination. Please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have characters outside the ascii-range inside your perl-script you have to `use utf8` and ensure that your script is stored in the utf-8 encoding (it is).

The main purpose nowadays for `use utf8` is to tell perl that your script is stored in utf8. If you want to use it for something else, read `perldoc perlunicode` first, probably you'll need some other pragma or module.

Also you didn't state what your database driver is. Probably your database is capable of either storing the value as binary data, you can then decode it with `Encode::decode`, or your driver is capable of storing utf-8 text, then you could use that.

Comment: I have added 'use utf8' in my script,  added  
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");  before printing the result. But same error I am getting It is displaying   Â£ in UI

Comment: It _should_ work this way. can you make a script with just `use utf8; use HTML::Entities; print encode_entities("£");` it should print `&pound;`.

Comment: yes , It is printing &pound; But while inserting in DB it  is changing it as &Acirc;&pound;

Comment: You could test with a `print "$str\n"` right before your `execute` what your variable contains. If it prints `&pound;` The problem is within your database driver. If it prints `&acirc;&pound;` You have encoded the string twice somewhere. A saner way to do this is to use the debugger and find out where it gets broken. Run your script with `perl -d`. `n` goes to the next command, `x $str` prints the contents `$str`, `s` goes into an command (you can use this to find out if your db-driver does some wrong encoding, maybe you forgot to set an option somewhere).

Comment: I found that actual problem causing this is, That  "£" data is coming from textbox  field from UI,  after encoding it is converting as &acirc;&pound;         Some htmlentities issue.. Please tell me how to fix this

Comment: I have added  $dbh->do("SET NAMES 'utf8'");   in my script so It is inserting properly ,But fetching the same data  '£' from DB to UI  is  displaying  as Â£.

Comment: You should really ask another question, or update this one, since the input from somewhere and a string literal are two totally different things. Whichever of these options you choose, you'll have to include more information! UI can literally be anything. Is it [gtk](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Gtk-Perl/Gtk/cookbook.pod), [Wx](https://metacpan.org/pod/Wx), or something else? If your UI is a webpage, what framework are you using? Dancer, Mojolicious, Catalyst, CGI.pm or something different? Are you using mod_perl? UI can mean so much things, you'll have to be a little more specific.