# Escaping latin characters for DB insertion and fetching with perl

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I am entering a note value  as "£" from html Text area  and submitting . and trying to insert into DB using following code, but  it is taking some junk value from UI and display also showing junk value  ,Ex: If I enter £ from text area , It is coming as  Â£. Please tell me how to fix this issue.

```
#!/usr/local/perl-5.20.1/bin/perl
use HTML::Entities;
my $str= $cgi->param('note');
$str=HTML::Entities::encode($str);
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO notes VALUES (null,'FD',?,?)");
$sth->execute('1','2',time(),$str);

my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT ATTuid, noteDate, content FROM notes WHERE requestType = ? AND requestID = ? ORDER BY noteDate ".$order);
$sth->execute('1','2');
if ($sth->rows() > 0) {
while (my @temp = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
$temp[2] =~ s|'|\\'|g;
$html = '<br/>'.$temp[2];
}
```

Comment: Have you configured $dbh to communicate in UTF-8 or some other encoding?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encoding of latin characters like £ (pound) is throwing junk value after encoding using perl script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30392557/encoding-of-latin-characters-like-%c2%a3-pound-is-throwing-junk-value-after-encodin)

Comment: Please don't ask the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30392557/176646) multiple times (this is the third). You marked an answer to your first question as accepted, even though you still haven't resolved your issue. Instead of asking the same question again, edit your original post to clarify the issue and to answer questions people left in comments. You can notify people in comments by responding with `@username`, e.g. `@ThisSuitIsBlackNot`. Don't accept an answer unless your issue is resolved. If you still don't get a satisfactory answer, you can post a bounty to get more attention.

Comment: What does your stack look like? Do you have a html page? Are you generating the page with some sort of cgi module? What is that `$cgi` object? Are you using blank `CGI.pm` or `CGI::Prototype`? Are you using [one of these](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives)? In the comments to my answer in the other question you found out, that the database has nothing to do with it. You could delete the whole database code from your question and just ask how to properly get utf-8 encoded strings from a textbox generated by framework/in the form `X` to perl web frame work `Y`.

Answer (score 4):

It seems a problem related to a possible character set mismatch between the application or the HTML page and the underling database server, What I suggest to you is to go with UTF-8 encoding on both sides.

In the web page (if that is what you have) should begin with :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

In my.cnf of MySQL Server :

```
init_connect = 'SET NAMES utf8'
```

or from perl :

```
$dbh->do( "set names utf8" );
```

or when you establish the connection :

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect(
    "dbi:mysql:dbname=db_name", 
    "db_user", "db_pass",
     {RaiseError => 0, PrintError => 0, mysql_enable_utf8 => 1}
 ) or die "Connect to database failed.";
```

Answer (score 2):

You should [ensure MySQL is set to use utf-8](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-applications.html) and add the following before prepare:

```
$dbh->do("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Hope that helps... Leave a comment if you have further problems.

Per comment, you now need an [HTML meta tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp) within your head block to set the text encoding:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<!-- rest goes here -->
</html>
```

Best of luck to you.

Comment: @ hd1, Thanks a lot, I have added above in my script, '£'  is inserting properly  .   But in fetching the same data in displaying into Text area is displaying as Â£

Comment: This is a separate question, but forcing the content-type to utf-8 in your HTML should sort you. Please see my edit.

Comment: While inserting the latin chatacter data into DB we need add following lines in script  use utf8;
 use HTML::Entities; 
$dbh->do("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
                                                                                                                    While fetching the data we need to  add this line before fetch the data      $dbh->do("SET NAMES 'latin1'");

Comment: That would depend on your system locale settings -- mine are all UTF-8, so I needn't set names to latin1.